# Python3-LDAP not returning expected results

Tags: python, database, curl, python-3.x, ldap

I'm using the Python 3 LDAP library [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python3-ldap). I don't understand its behavior with regards to the '<=' operator.

I have a range of `uidNumber`s that I need to test for specific values. I'm breaking the range up in to chunks so I can parallelize each section. So, the filters on the queries look like:

`(&(uid=MY_UID)(&(uidNumber>=chunk_start)(uidNumber<=chunk_end)))`

The `uidNumber` associated with the `uid` I'm searching for is in between `chunk_start` and `chunk_end`. However. Running the query above on an `ldap3.Connection` object returns no results. Specifically, I get back:

```
[{'description': 'success',
  'dn': '',
  'message': '',
  'referrals': None,
  'result': 0,
  'type': 'searchResDone'}]
```

Running the same query through `curl` produces the correct result, so I poked around more in `ldap3`. I found that queries with the `>=` operator worked as expected, but nothing with the `<=` operator ever produced any results. Searching for both a `uidNumber` and a `uid` produces the following:

```
In [175]: res = c.search('######' 
                '(&(uid=######)(uidNumber<=#######))', 
                 ldap3.SEARCH_SCOPE_WHOLE_SUBTREE, 
                 attributes=['objectClass', 'displayName'])

In [176]: c.getResponse(res)
Out[176]: 
[{'description': 'success',
  'dn': '',
  'message': '',
  'referrals': None,
  'result': 0,
  'type': 'searchResDone'}]
```

Switching the `<=` for `>=` and leaving the `uidNumber` in the query the same produces the correct result.

I also noticed that if I drop the `uid` parameter, `getResult` returns `None`, rather than a list with no results.

What's going wrong here?

EDIT:

Grepping 'uidNumber` in the schema produces this result:

```
attributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.1.0 NAME 'uidNumber' DESC 'Standard LDAP attribute type' SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.27 SINGLE-VALUE X-ORIGIN 'RFC 2307' )
objectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.0 NAME 'posixAccount' DESC 'Standard LDAP objectclass' SUP top AUXILIARY MUST ( cn $ uid $ uidNumber $ gidNumber $ homeDirectory ) MAY ( userPassword $ loginShell $ gecos $ description ) X-ORIGIN 'RFC 2307' )
```

Looking up RFC 2307, in turn, says this:

```
( nisSchema.1.0 NAME 'uidNumber'
          DESC 'An integer uniquely identifying a user in an
                administrative domain'
          EQUALITY integerMatch SYNTAX 'INTEGER' SINGLE-VALUE )
```

Does the `EQUALITY integerMatch` line mean that it doesn't support ordering? Is it just a fluke that `curl` is returning correct results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordering is defined in the LDAP schema. Check if your uidNumber has the integerOrderingMatch ordering rule - if it doesn't, anything strange can happen.

Also, your pasted code

```
(&(uid=MY_UID)(&(uidNumber>=chunk_start)(uidNumber<=chunk_end))
```

is missing a `)` at the end, is this a copy/paste error or the same in your real code? My python is quite rusty, but in the error message, i'd assume a `,` is missing at the end of line 175 as well.

Comment: The same query works when I submit it via curl, so I assumed that it was supported by the server? That's a copy-paste error -- the `ldap3` module correctly raises an error for malformed filters. I don't follow what you mean by the missing `,`? The syntax of the code I pasted is correct, the trailing `,` in lists is optional. I pulled down the info in the schema and I'll paste it in the body of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of the python3-ldap library. You are right, there is a bug in the library while processing the <= operator.

I've fixed it in the upcoming 0.8.0 version of python3-ldap.

Bye,
Giovanni